# How to replace multi-words with a single word in typescript?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I want to replace multi-words in a single string with one word. I tried this but only first word is replacing.

Here is the code.

```
function addReplacement(text: string): string 
{
  return text.replace(/\bdrink\b/g || /\btea\b/g ,'****')
}
```

Input string: `I like to drink a cup of tea.`

Output: `I like to **** a cup of tea.`

What I want is: `I like to **** a cup of ****.`

How to do that? Please Help.

Comment: You are applying "||" operator to two regexes, which will surely not produce a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `||` operator is just going to return the left side, because a regex is a truthy value in javascript. The `||` operator is meant to operate on boolean values.

What you want is a regex that matches a word boundary, then either drink or tea, and then another word boundary. That would be typed like this:

```
function addReplacement(text: string): string {
  return text.replace(/\b(drink|tea)\b/g ,'****')
}
```

The parentheses in the regex are a group, and the `|` is the OR operator.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoEoFMAOAbZCLAWyzCgAoosAPKALkQGcoAnGMAcwEpGX2uiAN4BYAFCJErLFBCsk1OgDpp+QlgoB6ADoAjCqgEBrAD7Vk3PZs6IANAHIAVM8f3u4gL7jxEBEzh4WEp4cJwUaJi4BESk5BQARACSiHgwRliIUHCIhhxGKIgQIDiIcMCZWMjx3NxAA)

Comment: this is working great for this text `I like to drink a cup of tea.`

Comment: but not working for this `Iliketodrinkacupoftea.` what would be the solution to this?

Comment: @JamshaidAlamDJ remove the word boundaries, (the \b)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use double replace instead of double pipe!

```
function addReplacement(text: string): string 
{
  return text.replace(/\bdrink\b/g ,'****').replace(/\btea\b/g ,'****')
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A working version would be

```
text.replace(/\s[drink|tea]\s/g ,'****')
```

Comment: Is if it's not working for you, you need to show us the content of "text".

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in your regex, you want to use the or `|` inside regex, not pass "one or the other regex"

```
text.replace(/\b(drink|tea)\b/g,'****')
```

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo, fixed it! Can you try again